# How to call out to another app within an app - iOS

Tags: ios

We use an LMS calles Canvas by instructure. Our students access the LMS via the iOS app, however we would like to be able to call out from this app to another app (e-book reader).
We just want to be able to select a link which will redirect us to the app.
We have a coder in our staff, and we would really appreciate any advise on how to achieve the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with URL Schemes between apps [Apple Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2)
And here is [Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629) explaining URL Schemes implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the e-book reader app's codebase, this is simple to achieve by specifying a [URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) this app may respond to (or, alternatively, if you happen to know what [URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) this app supports). Then it will be as simple as calling out a URL of a corresponding format from within the iOS app your students use.

Alternatively, if your app provides access to the documents of some sort, you could look into [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/index.html) that can add *"Open in..."* functionality to your app, allowing app users to open a document in an arbitrary app that supports this file format.